# USB port malfunction after turning off Toshiba's ACPI

Tags: boot, laptop, usb, linux-mint, toshiba-laptop

I had to manually shut down the computer while running SimCity 4 Deluxe. Upon booting, the computer froze up at "`toshiba_acpi` Toshiba Extras."

I then added `acpi=off` into grub.cfg to allow me to boot into Linux Mint. Battery information like power and temperature were not shown on the battery meter. As the only option I could think of, I blacklisted the line `toshiba_acpi`. After that, I noticed that whatever I inserted into the USB ports could not be detected in Mint or the BIOS.

I completely dismantled  the computer to replug the USB connection to the motherboard, but that didn't help. I originally thought that the manual shutdown resulted in a power surge, causing the USB ports to fail, which made booting freeze up at `toshiba_acpi`. However, when I connect an Optical Mouse, the red laser appears; so I'm now skeptical it was a power surge.

The motherboard and all other hardware seems fine, I completely disassembled the computer to replug the connections.

How can I fix it? I've tried everything I can think of...

I have a Toshiba Satellite L500D running Linux Mint 13.

Comment: I noticed this problem this morning when I was trying to run Ysflight with a usb joystick, mouse, and keyboard.

Comment: Try booting with the driver enabled but the USB port header disconnected.  If it was a power surge this will confirm the problem is a hardware problem.

Comment: That's a bit of good news, the rest of my hardware works PERFECTLY fine, actually better than before. I don't think a missing driver is the cause, then usb devices would show up in the BIOS at least.

Comment: USB port header, what is that?

Comment: The USB header is located on the motherboard.  Its what makes the USB Ports work.  I assumed you what it was since you already reconnected the cable.

Comment: Yes, I researched that last night anyway. But my computer is a LAPTOP, IT IS A PAIN IN THE BUTT TO DECOMPILE, and one usb port is under the motherboard which makes it worse. If I do what you said, how will I know if it is a hardware issue?

please answer ASAP, thanks
PLMA

Comment: I already explained how it would confirm its a hardware issue.  If there isn't an actual USB interface but the driver is still loaded, you are able to confirm the problem is with the hardware, and not the interigity of the system. **Hardware often fails for no reason at all.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the problem was caused by a power surge, it is possible that it caused damage to your hardware.
If it is the case, these is not much you can do from the software side.
Try to see if the OS detects all of your hardware, if some pieces fail to be recognized you could try to install it in another machine to make sure that it is damaged, and, it it is the case, substitute it with new ones.

Comment: Drivers are fine, PC was recently updated anyway. In the BIOS, no usb devices found.

Comment: I wasn't talking about drivers, if an electrical surge has occured, it may have caused physical damage to the hardware, not some malfunction by the software side. If the USB post was burnt, you would need to substitute it.

Comment: Sorry, that was a response Ramhound's comment.

Comment: Yes, the rest of the hardware is detected.

Comment: I believe the only option now is to repair the hardware since I highly doubt it's software issue; I'm just afraid that if I but new hardware it might not work. What do you suggest I do: send the computer to a technician, or save money by buying new USB ports?

please reply ASAP,
PLMA

Comment: That's up to you. If you are confident enough and know how to do it, you can try, otherwise let someone skilled do the job. But you must decide yourself, based on your judgement.

Comment: I've taken the computer apart before and I know where the parts go. I'm just not sure what is causing the problem, a bios problem, a motherboard issue, or a broken set of usb ports.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I was left to only one choice; I replaced the motherboard ($90). The usb ports, fan, and speakers work better now.